# How to interpret coefficient in log-log regression?

Tags: regression, sas, interpretation

I am trying use log-log regression with sample data, whereby a 1% increase in x is associated with a 25% increase in y - see example SAS code below.  I expected the regression coefficient for log_x to be 25.0, but proc glimmix yielded 22.43.

Please advise.  I do not know how to interpret log-log regression coefficients given the discrepancy above.

```
data log_log_regression;
    retain x 1 y 1;
    output;
    do i = 1 to 100;
        x = 1.01*x;
        y = 1.25*y;
        log_x = log(x);
        output;
    end;
    drop i;
run;

proc glimmix data=log_log_regression;
    model y = log_x / link = log solution;
    run;
quit;
```

Comment: It is no accident that $\exp(0.2243)\approx 1.25$. You got exactly what you asked for. :-)